# Continues free snapshot backup manager for ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, rsync, snapshot

Is there a easy-to-use full-system snapshot manager for ubuntu?

Use-case: After a complete system breakdown (e.g. rm -rf /bin) the ability to restore the previous system state.

I tried to use rsync, but didn't understand how to apply such functionality with that.
Edit:
Mabye the requirement for a "snapshot" mechanism was misleading.
 A good analogy for the solution I'm looking for is like a docker commit command, a stable image of my system that I could use if something goes sideways

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a full-system and incremental backup solution. This question has a little different focus but I think it might be an answer to what you are looking for.

[Which is Most TimeMachine-like Backup Program for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647495/which-is-most-timemachine-like-backup-program-for-ubuntu)

And here are some other alternatives.

https://alternativeto.net/software/time-machine/?platform=linux

Comment: By using back in time, and setting the directory I want to take the snapshot of to "/" I am practically taking a snapshot of the whole system, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @DsCpp that seems reasonable to me. I do worry that certain areas may be dangerous to backup this way, e.g. /proc /dev. Also, /mnt /media and /snap could potentially cause issues if you back them up.

Comment: indeed, i've incountered problems with this method in all solutions you provided ("unbackable folder" backintime called it). A good analogy for the solution I'm looking for is like a docker commit command, a stable image of my system, so I could use if something goes sideways